# PowerBI/PowerQuery subtract data from previous row

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery

Working in Powerbi/PowerQuery and need to subtract the current value from the previous value.
The row "Id" is a unique number that is a continuous count.

I've attached an "output" example made in excel with expected output.

Though I have no idea how to get that working in Power Query, so hoping for some help and a solution here.

Looking forward to your reply.
Thank you in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4jIO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfR6e.png)

Searched on google, and that brought me here, though without finding what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a calculated column for a RANK ID, you can do that by using RANKX function

> RankColumn = RANKX(Table, Table[Id], ASC,Dense)

After that you can easily get the row before the one you are, with another final calculated column.

> SubstractColumn = Table[Data1] - CALCULATE(MAX(Table[Data1]),FILTER(RankColumn = MAX(Table[RankColumn] - 1)

Comment: Hi Alejandro

I'ved tried, but failed.
The RANKx function, doesnt give me the option to use Table.

The table name is: Speed

i have these options: 
CalculateTable
DataTable
RelatedTable